# libxpc.dylib arm64 build error

Tags: ios, xcode6, arm64

I have created an objective c static library target 7.0+, trying to run it in an app on device running arm64 **fails** getting:

`'/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib', missing required architecture arm64 in file /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib (2 slices) for architecture arm64 in compile/build time`.

My architecures has: `arm64`.
Build/compiling/running on ios 6 simualtor **works**. 
Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it there is a bug with developer site xcode it seems to be no the exact same version.
Uninstall xcode 6 and install from App Store.